# Best way to query for favorite list

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux

users have the ability to set a item as favorite, when pressing the star icon they set of a Redux function that sets this as a local favorite and saves this in the Firebase Database as well;

```
-Userfavorites
--userID
---ItemID: true (or false if the disable the favorite later on)
```

This all works well, however I'm now trying to figure out how it is best to handle the information when it is retrieved from Firebase. On opening of the app all items are retrieved, as wel as the above UserFavorites list.

What is the best way to handle this in my Redux state?

```
Component: {ItemID1: true, ItemID2: true, ItemID3: false}
                    or
Array: 0.[ItemID1: true]1.[ItemID2: true]2.[ItemID3: false]
```

When opening an item I want to cross check the itemID that is opened, if it Exists in the UserFavorites list in Redux AND is set to true the icon should so different from a value of false.
What I have found is that I cannot look into the Redux state with a variable (like state.items.userfavorites.ItemID === true (Where ItemID is the variable of the Item ID that is opened.) What is your preferred way of working with a favorite function and am I on the right track with using the favorites list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got this working yesterday. My Firebase Database still looks as above. Below is the Redux action. I create an array with this where every entry has the favID prefix followed by the key, which in my case is the itemID.

```
        const resData = await response.json();
        console.log('fetchFavorites action response data' , resData)
        const result = Object.entries(resData).map(([key, val]) => ({
            ['favID']: key
                        }));
                        console.log('results' , result)
        
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_FAVORITES,
            userFavorites: result
        });
```

Then on the detail page I use the following code to look if the currentItemIsFavorite.

```
const currentItemIsFavorite = useSelector(state => 
        state.onlineItems.favoriteItems.some(item => item.favID === itemId)
        );
```

After that generating the correct icon with this;

```
                <Item
                title="Favorite star"
                iconName={isFavorite  ? 'ios-star' : 'ios-star-outline'}
                color='gold'
                onPress={toggleFavorite}
            />
```